# How to pass a value to a builtin Linux kernel module at boot time?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I want to pass a custom parameter to the kernel at boot time,
which my new code will use. This parameter is a number.

I know how to pass value to kernel module using kernel command line i.e `module_param()`. Now i want to pass value from u-boot.

Is there a way to do this, either during or after boot?

Comment: Welcome to SO!  It's always helpful to leave a little bit of code so that potential posters get some context.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Modify your board file present in *include/config/board_xxx.h* of U-Boot, modify *$bootargs* similar to the last variable that is set in this example:

```
setenv bootargs display=\${display} console=\${consoledev},\${baudrate} root=/dev/mmcblk0p1 rw rootdelay=1 control.cmd1={cmd1}
```

*control* is the name of the built-in driver module that I cannot insmod because I need it for booting fully to the Linux prompt.

*cmd1* is the global variable I've defined in the module in which I've used:

```
module_param(cmd1, int, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IWGRP);
```

so, your *$bootargs* var simply needs to be appended with something like:

`<your_mod_name>.<your_mod_parameter_var_name>=<an_appropriate_value>`

Answer (score 15):

If you know how to pass a value to a kernel module, you know enough :)

`insmod my_module param=value`

If your module is built-in in the kernel, you can add your parameter to the kernel parameters

`vmlinux ... my_module.param=value ...`

Here a reference: [kernel-parameters.txt](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/kernel-parameters.txt)

Comment: Above is the solution for x86 architecture.

Comment: Above is the solution for x86 architechture.
I am working on ARM architecture and using U-boot as a boot loader. How can i do same from uboot.

Comment: It is the solution also for any other architecture, with any other bootloader. In uboot, you have the bootargs environment.

Answer (score 5):

**Linux source documentation**

I prefer it from the hourse's mouth [v4.12/Documentation/admin-guide/kernel-parameters.rst](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v4.12/Documentation/admin-guide/kernel-parameters.rst):

```
Module parameters can be specified in two ways: via the kernel command
line with a module name prefix, or via modprobe, e.g.:

    (kernel command line) usbcore.blinkenlights=1
    (modprobe command line) modprobe usbcore blinkenlights=1

Parameters for modules which are built into the kernel need to be
specified on the kernel command line.  modprobe looks through the
kernel command line (/proc/cmdline) and collects module parameters
when it loads a module, so the kernel command line can be used for
loadable modules too.
```

**Easy way to try it out**

```
CONFIG_DUMMY_IRQ=y
```

then on the command line:

```
dummy-irq.irq=12
```

and when the kernel boots you see:

```
dummy-irq: registered for IRQ 12
```

which is printed from the `init` of `dummy-irq.c`.

**Code path**

I didn't manage to follow the full code path yet, but I think the `.` is encoded at https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v4.12/include/linux/moduleparam.h#L13:

```
#define MODULE_PARAM_PREFIX KBUILD_MODNAME "."
```

which gets expanded in the `module_param` macro waterfall, one step of which contains a comment by Linus that indicates how clear that code is:

```
/* Lazy bastard, eh? */
```

The QEMU GDB `watch` backtrace that ends up setting it for `dummy-irq.c:irq` is:

```
#0  kstrtouint (s=<optimized out>, base=<optimized out>, res=0xffffffff81a8d820 <irq>) at lib/kstrtox.c:225
#1  0xffffffff8106e124 in param_set_uint (val=<optimized out>, kp=<optimized out>) at kernel/params.c:295
#2  0xffffffff8106ed98 in parse_one (handle_unknown=<optimized out>, arg=<optimized out>, max_level=<optimized out>, min_level=<optimized out>, num_params=<optimized out>, params=<optimized out>, doing=<optimized out>, val=<optimized out>, param=<optimized out>) at kernel/params.c:148
#3  parse_args (doing=<optimized out>, args=0xffff880007fdb99f "", params=<optimized out>, num=<optimized out>, min_level=<optimized out>, max_level=<optimized out>, arg=0x0 <irq_stack_union>, unknown=0xffffffff81aeb8e5 <unknown_bootoption>) at kernel/params.c:243
#4  0xffffffff81aebc6d in start_kernel () at init/main.c:518
```